# How can i Loop TABLE TD with specific date and time range in PHP HTML

Tags: php, html

I am trying to build a for loop so that i don't need to write it one by one,

i have a list 16 TD.

If today is February 25,

the TH `hour` will have its value of

```
ID  |  HOUR       |60 |30 |45 |0 |ADJUSTED |HG |STRETCH |UG |HC
1      Feb 25 6PM
2      Feb 25 7PM
3      Feb 25 8PM
4      Feb 25 9PM
5      Feb 25 10PM
6      Feb 25 11PM
7      Feb 25 12AM
8      Feb 26 1AM
9      Feb 26 2AM
10     Feb 26 3AM
11     Feb 26 4AM
12     Feb 26 5AM
13     Feb 26 6AM
14     Feb 26 7AM
15     Feb 26 8AM
```

how can i make a loop consist of date?

here is the code that i have currently.

```
 <table class="table table-striped" id="user_set_goal_table" width="100%">
                         <thead>
                             <tr>
                                 <th>#</th>
                                 <th>Hour</th>
                                 <th>HC-60</th>
                                 <th>HC-30</th>
                                 <th>HC-45</th>
                                 <th>HC-0</th>
                                 <th class="th_red">Adjusted HC</th>
                           <th class="th_yellow">Hourly Goal</th>
                           <th class="th_yellow">Stretch</th>
                           <th class="th_yellow">Updated Goal</th>
                           <th class="th_green">Transfers/HC</th>
                             </tr>
                         </thead>
                         <tbody>
                        <?php
                        for ($i = 1;$i <= 16;$i++)
                        {
                        ?>
                         <tr>
                             <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                             <td><?php echo "a" . $i; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "<input type='text'  id='hc_60_" . $i . "'  "; ?></td>
                             <td><?php echo "<input type='text'  id='hc_30_" . $i . "'  "; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "<input type='text'  id='hc_45_" . $i . "'  "; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "<input type='text'  id='hc_0_" . $i . "'  "; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "f" . $i; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "g" . $i; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "h" . $i; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "i" . $i; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "j" . $i; ?></td>
                         </tr>
                         <?php
                         }
                        ?>
                         </tbody>
                     </table>
```

the time is always static the only thing will change is the date.
any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: how the first record is connected with the current time, i.e. what should be the first time if the date is today?

Comment: the first time will be always 6PM and i will end at 8AM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we stay with your code you can simply use modify() method on date object for example:

```
$referenceDate = new DateTimeImmutable('today 06:00PM');

for ($i = 1; $i <= 16; $i++) {
    //...
    echo $referenceDate->modify(sprintf("+ %s hours", $i))->format('M d gA');
    //...
}
```

Comment: Hi sir, last question, what if there is a input date. and i choose a date there? how can i display the value from it to my for loop?

Comment: Hi, all you need is probably `referenceDate` variable manipulation, just pass the date as an argument for example:

`$inputVal = '2010-01-02 06:00';
$referenceDate =new DateTimeImmutable($inputVal)`

or if you need fixed 6pm just use:

`$inputVal = '2010-01-02 06:00';
$referenceDate =(new DateTimeImmutable($inputVal))->modify('06:00PM');`

Does it help you?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should very similar `for` or `foreach` loop for range of `days` you have.

1. You have to specify the range of `$days` you want to process (with hardcoded values, DateTime etc.
2. Loop through it (this loop is outer for existing one in your code)

```
<?php foreach ($days as $day) {
?>
 // here put your loop and use $day variable
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi sir how can i implement the loop of it from my existing code?

Comment: Use this new loop right after `tbody` and your existing loop paste inside that outer one. Enclose outer loop after your current loop.

Answer (score -2):

Please use datatable ajax request method:

HTML:

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "server-site.php"
} );
```

} );

check out for reference:

[Datatable Server Side Process](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side)

Comment: Thanks for this, but this is not the problem that i have right now.

Comment: Can you explain me in details I so that I can help you